# Two line ListView - combine alphabet scroller and section headers

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have recently and successfully created a two line list view in Android Studio. However what I would like to do now is to implement alphabetical scrolling and section headers for letters of the alphabet that contain items beginning with that letter e.g. items beginning with A to be under a section header named 'A'. I also want section headers for letters containing empty content not to appear i.e. for the letter 'W' if there are no items in my list begging with W then I don't want the 'W' section header to appear etc.

The image below is what my activity currently looks like, and the image below that is what I am trying to achieve (two lines per item not one). The 4 sections of code below represent what I have used to create my list view (as seen in the first image).

Please bear in mind all that needs to be done is to add an alphabet scroller and section headers hence I would be very grateful if when giving an answer to provide the most efficient way of achieving the above as well as indicating if something needs to be added, taken away or even combined.

[image: Bakerloo line list]
[image: list with alphabet scroller and section headers]

actitivty_bakerloo_line.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.apptacularapps.exitsexpertlondonlite.BakerlooLineActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/BakerloolineListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

BakerlooLineActivity.java

```
package com.apptacularapps.exitsexpertlondonlite;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class BakerlooLineActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bakerloo_line);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#B36305")));
        getActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>Bakerloo line</font>"));

        ArrayList<SearchResults> searchResults = GetSearchResults();

        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.BakerloolineListView);
        lv.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(this, searchResults));

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Object o = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                SearchResults fullObject = (SearchResults)o;
            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<SearchResults> GetSearchResults(){
        ArrayList<SearchResults> results = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();

        SearchResults sr = new SearchResults();
        sr.setStation("Baker Street");
        sr.setFareZone("Fare zone 1");
        results.add(sr);

        sr = new SearchResults();
        sr.setStation("Charing Cross");
        sr.setFareZone("Fare zone 1");
        results.add(sr);

        sr = new SearchResults();
        sr.setStation("Edgware Road");
        sr.setFareZone("Fare zone 1");
        results.add(sr);

        return results;
    }
}
```

SearchResults.java

```
package com.apptacularapps.exitsexpertlondonlite;

public class SearchResults {
    private String station = "";
    private String fareZone = "";

    public void setStation(String station) {
        this.station = station;
    }
    public String getStation() {
        return station;
    }

    public void setFareZone(String fareZone) {
        this.fareZone = fareZone;
    }
    public String getFareZone() {
        return fareZone;
    }
}
```

MyCustomBaseAdapter.java

```
package com.apptacularapps.exitsexpertlondonlite;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.apptacularapps.exitsexpertlondonlite.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchResults> results) {
        searchArrayList = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return searchArrayList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return searchArrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dualline_row_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtStation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.station);
            holder.txtFareZone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.farezone);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtStation.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getStation());
        holder.txtFareZone.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getFareZone());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtStation;
        TextView txtFareZone;
    }
}
```

**Side list**
[image: side list]

```
package com.apptacularapps.exitsexpertlondonlite;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Bakerloo_line extends Activity {

    ListView sideList;


    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    ListView listview=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bakerloo_line);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#B36305")));
        getActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>Bakerloo line</font>"));


        listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_Bakerlooline);

        items.add(new SectionItem("My Friends"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Abhi Tripathi", "Champpu"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Sandeep Pal", "Sandy kaliya"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Amit Verma", "Budhiya"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Awadhesh Diwaker ", "Dadda"));

        items.add(new SectionItem("Android Version"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Jelly Bean", "android 4.2"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("IceCream Sandwich", "android 4.0"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Honey Comb", "android 3.0"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Ginger Bread ", "android 2.2"));

        items.add(new SectionItem("Android Phones"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Samsung", "Galaxy"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Sony Ericson", "Xperia"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Nokia", "Lumia"));


        EntryAdapter adapter = new EntryAdapter(this, items);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);



        sideList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.sideIndex);
        List<String> sideIndexList = new ArrayList<String>();
        sideIndexList.add("A");
        sideIndexList.add("B");
        sideIndexList.add("C");
        sideIndexList.add("D");
        sideIndexList.add("E");
        sideIndexList.add("F");
        sideIndexList.add("G");
        sideIndexList.add("H");
        sideIndexList.add("I");
        sideIndexList.add("J");
        sideIndexList.add("K");
        sideIndexList.add("L");
        sideIndexList.add("M");
        sideIndexList.add("N");
        sideIndexList.add("O");
        sideIndexList.add("P");
        sideIndexList.add("Q");
        sideIndexList.add("R");
        sideIndexList.add("S");
        sideIndexList.add("T");
        sideIndexList.add("U");
        sideIndexList.add("V");
        sideIndexList.add("W");
        sideIndexList.add("X");
        sideIndexList.add("Y");
        sideIndexList.add("Z");

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.side_index_row,sideIndexList );
        sideList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                //When clicked, go to specific activity
                if(position == 0) {
                    //code specific to first list item
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Bakerloo_line.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**XML page**

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_Bakerlooline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/sideIndex"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ff996633"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**side_index_row.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/side_index_row"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:gravity="center">
</TextView>
```

Comment: You should start changing your listview for a section header listview. Google for examples.

Comment: OK. I'll get back to you when I've done that

Comment: You have to investigate also if you could use an expandable listview. Then you could do without the letter scroller.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am not looking to use an expandable one.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any examples of sectioned list views with two lines

Comment: ???? The second one if you google for `android sectioned listview example'. So this one: http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/  But maybe this is not the official sectioned listview. Sorry never experimented with one. But then: also the third result has it: http://sunil-android.blogspot.nl/2013/08/section-header-listview-in-android.html With exactly the layout you want. Pictures ... icons

Comment: Android Amazing ListView: https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/  Anything else?

Comment: OK I have followed this one [http://sunil-android.blogspot.nl/2013/08/...](http://sunil-android.blogspot.nl/2013/08/section-header-listview-in-android.html) but received errors that I don't know how to fix. Above is the edited question showing what I have done (should appear shortly).

Comment: Just remove those attributes from that .xml file. You don't need those design things.

Comment: After removing those, I get these errors (2nd attempt).

Comment: Sorry i can not see in which java/com/... directory you placed the files. You addded the files to your existing project? If so then i still do not know how you did it. The errors come while (on the first line of the java file) the package name is differen from yours. What you could do is place the .java files in the same directory als the one in which is your activity that is gonna use them and change the package name to yours.

Comment: You have seen that mister sinus in the .xml files uses lovercase? `<linearlayout android:l` ? Change that in all .xml files to `<LinearLayout android:l`. Do also all other tags. Also mister sinus is not ashamed that he copied all from Bartinger ( as you can reed in the comments). Bartinger: http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/

Comment: Just fixed those errors and now no errors are present within my project. However after rebuilding and deploying my app to the emulator the app crashes when I go to the page containing the list view (3rd attempt).

Comment: Then you can see the cause in the LogCat. Dont you use that? You should! Please have a look and copy/paste some lines to here. I know already what the error is but think it is better that you open the logcat and read the reason there yourself.

Comment: I believe it is to do with the list not being able to be inflated.

Comment: The ClassNotFoundExpection is something different from what i had expected. Are there no other errors or exceptions? I thought that having added a new Activity to your project you had forgotten to mention it in the manifest file. But then you could see that in the logcat.

Comment: No. What you see in the screenshot (page errors) are the errors I received.

Comment: In an .xml file you have `<listview android:id=` That should be `<ListView android:id=`. I warned you for that. Inspect all files! In the logcat the error is about `Listview`.

Comment: I found the problem. This line of code was missing in the 'list_item_section.xml' file `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`. Btw my java page has also been update to fix the issue (see **Problem solved** above). What do I need to do now to get the alphabet scroller?

Comment: Please be as kind as to react on the errors i found. Is the listview in a class that extends Activity? Or ListActivity? If the latter then convert to Activity first.

Comment: It extends ListActivity. Apologies for my impatience.

Comment: What do you mean by convert to "Activity first".

Comment: That it extends from Activity instead. So you are forced to make an .xml layout file in which you mention a ListView. Then you can add others views too. If you are done then you can add another ListView for the Alphabet scroller.

Comment: I've created a xml layout file containing those two things but don't really know how to resolve the errors in the java file (see XML with 2 items)

Comment: Which two things? Which errors? Which java file? You are not very informative. And I think you informed us wrong by stating that your (new) activity expanded from ListActivity. Because why would you have done so when sinus didn't. You are messing it all up.

Comment: Please have a look above at the section called **Problem 16/09/14** and let me know if anything needs to change within that code. Thanks.

Comment: I already told you more than once that if your activity expands from ListActivity that you have to change that first. I also gave you the reason why you have to do so.

Comment: By changing it, I assume you meant from `extends ListActivity` to `extends Activity`

Comment: Tbh I don't know the proper way of converting from ListActivity to Activity

Comment: On this page you have posted several avtivities that extend from Activity like `public class BakerlooLineActivity extends Activity` and use a listview. And sunil used extended from Activity too. So one might wonder why you ended up with a list activity.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea how that happened. I've fixed the java page to Activity as necessary (check the section above titled 'ListActivity to Activity').

Comment: Well if that all works again. Then ok. You know now what you can do next because i already told you. But i will repeat. Add another ListView to activity_bakerloo_line.xml. Put both in a horizontal linear layout. And in the java make an arrayadapter with A-Z for it.

Comment: I've done the linear layout but I don't know how to do an array adapter with A-Z for it (check the 'LinearLayout' section above).

Comment: Stop posting pictures. Post the text of the .xml file. I do not see two LisView's. Do you? Post the text.

Comment: It's attached within that section now.

Comment: The horizontal is missing in the linear layout. Now why cant you fill an adapter for yet another listview with an array containing A,B,C,....Z? You did that at least three times on this page only already. Just copy the code and fill with the letters.

Comment: I can't use the same code as the list with two rows. An error is bound to appear as only one row is required. Check above the section called '**1 row not 2**'

Comment: Do you want a sectioned list for the letters too? I dont think so. Do away with <Item>, sections, sectionheaders and all that stuf. You can make the most simple of listviews. Start with ArrayList<String> and add the letters. `only one row is required.` Wrong. You need 26 rows/items. But everey item only consits of one String/TextView.

Comment: OK I have created an ArrayList<String> list view. Please check the section above titled **Side List**.

Comment: Nice. Well done. Please show the xml.

Comment: They are now attached within the same section. Sorry for any inconvenience caused during this week.

Comment: Ok. Now have you got it working at selecting a letter and adjust the other listview?

Comment: I've just realised that there is a sample on GitHub and I will follow that. Thanks for your time. Could you please reply with an Answer so that I can tick it off and close this query please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start changing your listview for a section header listview. Google for examples.